# Hatcher 1.3. problem 16

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given maps $X\to Y\to Z$ such that both $Y\to Z$ and the composition $X\to Z$ are covering spaces, show that $X\to Y$ is a covering space if $Z$ is locally path-connected.

Comment: Yes, that is a homework problem from Hatcher's textbook.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Please anyone can help? I`m totally stuck in it.

Comment: I decided to do this problem and made some progress by considering the two coverings $\{U_\alpha \}$ and $\{V_\beta \}$ associated with the two covering maps $q: Y \to Z$ and $qp: X \to Z$, and looking at the cover of $Y$ by the disjoint sets in $\{ q^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap V_\beta) \}_{\alpha , \beta}$, but I don't see where local path-connectedness comes into play.  I'd appreciate if someone could contribute.

Comment: Seems like it looks a lot like Lemma 80.2. in Munkres.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise 1.3.16 in Hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182791/exercise-1-3-16-in-hatcher)