# Exercise 1.3.16 in Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer so I hope to find it now.

Let $p:X\to Y$ and $q:Y\to Z$ be maps such that $q$ and $q\circ p$ are covering map and $Z$ is locally path-connected. Then $p$ is a covering map, too. So, I choose $y\in Y$ and choose $U_y$ a neighbourhood of $y$ such that $q|_{U_y}:U_y\to q(U_y)$ is a homeomorphism. Then, the set $\{q(U_y)\colon y\in Y\}$ covers $Z$. We see that $(q\circ p)^{-1}(q(U_y))=p^{-1}(U_y)$. Now, I that I only have to show that $p|_{p^{-1}(U_y)}$ is a homeomorphism. How can I do this, and where do I need locally path-connectedness?

Comment: See problem 16 here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~reidh/AT/Hatcher_Algebraic-Topology-Solutions.pdf

Comment: Why do we need path connectedness of $p(U)$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let us first observe that Hatcher's definition of a covering map is somewhat unusual because he does not require surjectivity. Compare this with the definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space). We come back to this point later.

What you have to show is that

(1) $p^{-1}(U_y) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha$ with pairwise disjoint open $V_\alpha$ (which are called *sheets* over $U_y$) such that each $p_\alpha : V_\alpha \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} U_y$ is a homeomorphism.

This has nothing to do with showing that $p|_{p^{-1}(U_y)}$ is a homeomorphism. In general the latter will be *false*. Moreover, your approach cannot work because you do not use fact that $q$ is a covering map; you only invoke that $q$ is a local homeomorphism.

To prove (1), let $y \in Y$ and $W$ be an open neighborhood of $q(y)$ which is evenly covered by $q$ and by $q \circ p$. That is, $q^{-1}(W) = \bigcup_{\beta \in B} U_\beta$ with pairwise disjoint open $U_\beta$ such that each $q_\beta : U_\beta \stackrel{q}{\rightarrow} W$ is a homeomorphism, and $(q \circ p)^{-1}(W) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in C} V_\gamma$ with pairwise disjoint open $V_\gamma$ such that each $(q \circ p)_\gamma : V_\gamma \stackrel{q \circ p}{\rightarrow} W$ is a homeomorphism.

Let $\beta$ be the unique index with $y \in U_\beta$. Then take $U_y = U_\beta$. We get $p^{-1}(U_y) \subset (q \circ p)^{-1}(W)$, but it is not at all clear that $p^{-1}(U_y) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in C'} V_\gamma$ for some $C' \subset C$. Only if that is the case, we can conclude that for all $\gamma \in C'$ the map $p_\gamma : V_\gamma \to U_y$ is a homeomomorphism (because then $(q \circ p)_\gamma = q_\beta \circ p_\gamma$, i.e. $p_\gamma = q^{-1}_\beta \circ (q \circ p)_\gamma$).

So what can assure that for all $\beta$ there exists $C(\beta) \subset C$ such that $p^{-1}(U_\beta) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in C(\beta)} V_\gamma$? We shall see that this is true if $W$ is *connected*.

In fact, in this case the $V_\gamma$ are connected, that is, they are the *components* of $(q \circ p)^{-1}(W)$. This is a distinguishing feature of *connected* evenly covered $W$. No $V_\gamma$ can intersect more than one $p^{-1}(U_\beta)$ because otherwise we would get a partition of $V_\gamma$ into pairwise disjoint open sets. Therefore each $V_\gamma$ is contained in a unique $p^{-1}(U_{\beta(\gamma)})$. Since each $p^{-1}(U_\beta)$ is covered by the collection of all $V_\gamma$, we see that each $p^{-1}(U_\beta)$ is the union of suitable subcollection $\{ V_\gamma \mid \gamma \in C(\beta) \}$.

Which  assumption assures that each $z \in Z$ has a connected open neighborhhod which is evenly covered by $q$ and by $q \circ p$? This is that each $z \in Z$ has a neighborhood base consisting of connected open neighborhoods, i.e. the *local connectedness* of $Z$. This is a little weaker than local path-connectedness. So we can explicitly state

> If $Z$ is locally connected, then $p$ is a covering map in the sense of Hatcher.

If we adopt the standard definition of covering maps (including surjectivity), then $p$ is not necessarily a covering map because it may lack surjectivity. An example is this. Let $Y = Z \times \{ 0 , 1 \}$ and $q$ be the projection onto the first factor, let $X = Z$ and $q = id$, $p(z) = (z,0)$. Then $q$ and $q \circ p = id$ are (surjective) covering maps, but $p^{-1}(Z \times \{ 1 \})$ is empty.

This shows that we need an additional assumption assuring that $p$ is surjective. A trivial solution is to simply *amend* the requirement that $p$ is surjective. A less trivial alternative is to assume that $Y$ is *connected*. See my answer to  [$p:X\to Y$ covering space if $q\circ p:X\to Z$ and $q:Y\to Z$ covering spaces and $Z$ locally path-connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055199/px-to-y-covering-space-if-q-circ-px-to-z-and-qy-to-z-covering-spaces-an/3055957#3055957).