# Covering Transformations are covering maps theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

If $(\widetilde{X_1},p_1)$ and $(\widetilde{X_2},p_2)$ be two covering spaces for $X$ then a **Covering Transformation** is a continuous map $F : \widetilde{X_1} \to \widetilde{X_2}$ such that $p_1 = p_2 \circ F$.

I am trying to understand the following theorem

[image]

I am having difficulty in part "(22.32) **$F$ is a covering map**".
There is a sentence written saying

> We want to find an elementary neighborhood around $y_2$ together with a local inverse for $F$.

**Q1:** I can't understand why this is enough to prove that $F$ is a covering map.

**Q2:** Is there any difference between an elementary neighborhood and a usual neighborhood?

Comment: I think the point of this sentence is trying to outline that the author will prove that $y_2$ has an open neighborhood that is evenly covered by the map $F$ (thee is a disjoint collection of open sets, each of which are mapped homeomorphically onto the open nhbd of $y_2$). Note that a covering map is a local homeomorphism. So, I think an elementary nhbd just means an open nhbd, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question because you do not give much context. However, I am sure that for a covering map $p : E \to B$ an elementary open neigborhood of $b \in B$ is that what is usually denoted as an *evenly covered neigborhood*. This an open neigborhood $U$ of $b$ such that $p^{-1}(U) =  \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha$ with pairwise disjoint open $V_\alpha \subset E$, all of which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$. That is, all restrictions $p_\alpha : V_\alpha \stackrel{p}{\to} U$ are homeomorphisms. Certainly each of the homeomorphims $p_\alpha^{-1}  :  U \to V_\alpha$ is what the author understands as a local inverse for $p$.

This answers **Q2** : An arbitrary open neigborhood need not be elementary open neigborhood. As an example take the covering map $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = e^{2\pi it}$. Each point of $S^1$ has $S^1$ itself as an open neigborhood, but $S^1$ is certainly not an elementary open neigborhood.

Concerning **Q1** : "We want to find an elementary neighborhood around $y_2$ together with a local inverse for $F$". This is just what the *definition* of a covering map requires.

**Remark:**

It seems that the Theorem needs as an aditional assumption that $X$ is locally path connected (or at least that $X$ is locally connected). Perhaps this is a general assumption made by the author for all covering maps?

See [Exercise 1.3.16 in Hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3182791) to understand where the existence of *arbitrarily small connected neigborhoods* is needed.